# How to get admin path in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I used `JURI::base()` to get the admin path & it returns,

```
http://localhost/production/index.php
```

but,
I want the admin path of my site,
for e.g. `http://localhost/production/administrator/index.php`

How can I get the admin path ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below. [Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/root)

```
echo JURI::root().'administrator';
```

You can find more info [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Constants).